# Deserialize JSON with wrapped JSON inside a String using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am receiving a mix of JSON and string-wrapped JSON.
E.g.:

```
{
  "shapes": [
    {
      "type": "1",
      "shape": "{\"w\":3,\"h\":6}"
    },
    {
      "type": "2",
      "shape": "{\"radius\":5}"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to deserialize it with different object types.

```
abstract class Shape {
}

@Data
class Rectangle extends Shape {
    private int w;
    private int h;
}

@Data
class Circle extends Shape {
    private int radius;
}

@Data
class NodeParent {

    private Integer type;

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, property = "type")
    @JsonSubTypes({
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Rectangle.class, name = "1"),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Circle.class, name = "2")
    })
    private Shape shape;
}

@Data
class Root {

    private List<NodeParent> shapes;

}
```

This approach works with normal JSON (without that String wrapping)

But for my payload is fails, as it sees a String inside "shape". I can use a custom Deserializer for this. But then I would have to map all types there. I would've preferred using annotations.

Could this be done?

Comment: Well, the custom Deserializer could delegate to the standard deserializers for all but the "shape" field. Btw, why do you receive that escaped shape info? If you're the one defining the API I'd just require the sender not to do that.

Comment: It looks like internal `Circle` and `Rectangle` were double time serialised to `JSON`. First: `Object -> JSON String`, second: `JSON String -> JSON String`. You can add to each type static method which could look like this: `@JsonCreator
 public static Circle of(String value) throws IOException {
  return mapper.readValue(value, Circle.class);
 }`. For `Rectangle` it could look the same. `mapper` is `protected static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();` declared in `Shape` class. Maybe much simpler solution would be unescaping `JSON` before moving to deserialisation process.